# Non-Jews vs Zavim with respect to entering the Temple

Tags: gentiles, beis-hamikdash, maseches-niddah, zav-zava, maseches-keilim

In [Niddah 34a](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l6104.htm), the gemara says that the sages decreed *tumah* on non-Jews like that of a *zav* (translation edited from Soncino):

> ‮(ויקרא טו) דבר אל בני ישראל ואמרת אליהם איש איש כי יהיה זב בני ישראל מטמאין בזיבה ואין <העובדי כוכבים> {הנכרים} מטמאין בזיבה אבל גזרו עליהן שיהו כזבין לכל דבריהם
>
> "Speak to the children of Israel, and say to them, when any man has an issue" (Lev 15); only the children of Israel convey uncleanness by *zivah* and idolaters do not convey uncleanness by *zivah*, but a preventive measure has been enacted against them that they should be regarded as *zavim* in all respects.

However, in mishna [Keilim 1:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h61.htm) we see that *zavim* and non-Jews have different laws with respect to how far in the the Temple area they may enter (translation from [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.1.8?lang=bi)):

> ‮הר הבית, מקודש ממנו, שאין זבים וזבות נידות ויולדות נכנסין לשם.  החיל, מקודש ממנו, שאין גויים וטמא מת נכנסין לשם.
>
> The Temple Mount has greater sanctity, because men and women with discharges, menstruating women, and women who have given birth may not enter there. The Cheil [a low fence around the Temple, which served as a boundary, beyond which entry to those impure was prohibited] has higher sanctity, because gentiles and people contaminated with corpse impurity may not enter there.

Am I understanding correctly that there's a tension between these two sources? Why does the mishna treat non-Jews differently than *zavim* in something *tumah*-related?

Answer (score 2):

Mishna:

> ‏... הַחֵיל מְקֻדָּשׁ מִמֶּנּוּ, שֶׁאֵין גּוֹיִם וּטְמֵא מֵת נִכְנָסִים לְשָׁם...‏

See the Rash who asks your question:

> שאין נכרים וטמאי מתים נכנסים לשם - אע"ג דרבנן גזור על הנכרים שיהיו כזבים לכל דבריהם, לענין שילוח מחנות לא גזור עלייהו אלא כטמאי מתים. והאי דטמאי מתים אין נכנסים מן החיל ולפנים, היינו מדרבנן. דמדאורייתא אפילו בעזרת נשים שרו, שכל זה מחנה לויה עד עזרת ישראל ששם שער ניקנור:‏
>
> Non Jews and persons with Tumeat Met (death impurity) don't enter there. Despite that the Rabbis enacted that non Jews are as Zavim for all laws of uncleanness, with regard to removal from the camps, they enacted their status as Temeey Metim....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't see that this answers *why*.